# How to close tab in CMFCTabCtrl

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I have used CMFCTabCtrl in my MFC application and I have enabled the active tab close button.

```
m_TabControl.EnableActiveTabCloseButton();
```

But when I click close button,  the tab is not closed. How to  close the tab properly??..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the close button, a `WM_CLOSE` message is sent to the window that was used in the `AddTab` during initialisation.

So, in that child window, add a `WM_CLOSE` message handler and do something like this:

```
void CMyTabWindow::OnClose()
{
    // nb - must be created with the tab ctrl as parent
    CMFCTabCtrl *pTab = static_cast<CMFCTabCtrl*>(GetParent());
    pTab->RemoveTab(pTab->GetActiveTab());
}
```

Comment: @Zeus - my pleasure - in my tests it looks like everything is destroyed correctly, but better to check carefully anyway.

Comment: I have a problem. When Adding and removing tabs dynamically, I'm keeping the added tab dialogs in a vector<CMyDialog *> . But how can I remove the closed tab dialogs from the vector.  Any suggestion??..

Comment: @Zeus - I would store the `CMyDialog*` in a `std::set`, then you can `insert` or `erase` by value, which makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try with DeleteItem(index) on your CTabCtrl. This will remove the tab from your tab control.